# The folder contents could not be displayed - Operation not supported

Tags: nautilus, firefox, google-chrome, 22.04

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop, and it works fine.
The issue I have is when I download a file from the Internet with Firefox or Chrome browsers and try to rename the given name for a simple text, copied previously in the clipboard, using the Paste (Ctrl + v) function, this message shows:

[image: The folder contents could not be displayed - Operation not supported]

Does anybody know a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the copy.paste you want to use and the actual location of the file you want to change. I myself have no problems with this on any of the browser.

Comment: I recorded a video file that you can watch at this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/51fmbf2kwjma4u6/screencast.webm?dl=0. I noticed that it works if I use the paste function with the mouse (right-click and select the appropriate option on the shown menu). So, it only fails when I use the keys Ctrl+P.

Comment: Having the same issue. I've noticed a lot of issues in between Wayland, Gnome Desktop and nautilus in 22.04

Comment: See also: https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/issues/818 https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/-/issues/29 https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/-/issues/44 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk4/+bug/1971532 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk4/+bug/1972984 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408057/the-folder-contents-could-not-be-displayed-operation-not-supported

Comment: Today, I checked that the issue was fixed, maybe it was because of a recent Ubuntu update.